# Show HTML - passing data Property Lists

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I would like to ask some tips for a project I'm working on. I'm a Xcode beginner, so maybe is more easy than what I'm thinking.

So, the application I want to create shows a collection of data between two TableViews and it shows an image in a view controller at the end. 
I've implemented a Property Lists to manage the data between the TableViews and the ViewController.

Now, here my problem, I would like to show (in the last ViewController) an HTML file (stored in my resource folder) rather than just an image. Can someone help me to write down the code for that? I've been able to write the code for the image so far, which is:

**ViewController.h**

```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

   @interface MethodsViewController : UIViewController

   @property UIImage *bookCover;
   @property IBOutlet UIImageView *bookCoverView;

   @end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View Life Cycle
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

if (self.bookCover) {
    [self.bookCoverView setImage:self.bookCover];
}
}

@end
```

**SecondTableView.m**

prepare for segue

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

// Fetch Book Cover
NSDictionary *book = [self.books objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
self.bookCover =  [UIImage imageNamed:[book objectForKey:@"Cover"]];

// Perform Segue
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MethodsViewController" sender:self];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to deal with `UIWebView` for this. Add `UIWebView` property to your class:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWebView *aWebView;
```

Next, you need to represent content of your `HTML` file as an `NSString`, and it will be a content for the main page.

Lets just call this parameter as `webText`, in future we will load it into the web view, but first, - we need to get it.
To get `webText` parameter as an `NSString`, try the following code:

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"nameOfYourHTMLfile" ofType: @"html"];
NSString *webText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error: &error];
```

Set frame to `aWebView` in storyboard, then you can load `HTML` like this:

```
[self.aWebView loadHTMLString: webText baseURL: nil];
```

Comment: it shows me this errore: webText -> use of undeclared identifier "webText"